# golang call handler inside a handler

Tags: rest, go, http, go-gin

I want to use existing handler without actually send http request (http.Do or something like that), so I use gin.CreateTestContext(httptest.NewRecorder()) to create new *gin.Context to call existing Accept handler.

I have try to use c.Copy() to copy AcceptOrders context and use them to call existing Accept handler, but i get panic when c.JSON is called on existing Accept handler

I also have try to use c without copy to pass to existing Accept handler, but i cant overwrite c.JSON because its already been called on existing Accept handler

is there a better way to achieve what I want (calling existing handler in another handler)?

thank you for you response

```
func (cms *CmsOrderHandler) AcceptOrders(c *gin.Context) {
var referenceIds constant.OrderReferenceIDs
err := c.Bind(&referenceIds)
if err != nil {
    c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{
        "error":   "bad_request",
        "message": err.Error(),
    })
    return
}

if len(referenceIds.ReferenceIds) == 0 {
    c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{
        "error":   "bad_request",
        "message": err.Error(),
    })
    return
}

for _, referenceId := range referenceIds.ReferenceIds {
    r := httptest.NewRecorder()
    gin.SetMode(gin.ReleaseMode)
    cCopy, _ := gin.CreateTestContext(r)
    req, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodPost, "", nil)
    if err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{
            "error":   "internal server error",
            "message": err.Error(),
        })
        return
    }
    cCopy.Params = append(c.Params, gin.Param{Key: "reference_id", Value: referenceId})
    cCopy.Request = req
    cms.Accept(cCopy)
}

c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{})
}
```

Comment: *"call handler inside a handler"* -- sounds like a bad idea to me; why don't you turn the Accept handler's logic into a normal function that doesn't depend on the gin context, and then call that function from both Accept and AcceptOrders?

Comment: @mkopriva , well I can, but then there will be much change which I want to avoid, can I know the reason why its sound like a bad idea for you?

Comment: It's a bad idea on principle. If you're having trouble constructing the arguments for an API, you're not using the appropriate API. Relying on testing packages (httptest.NewRecorder, gin.CreateTestContext) in production code is just fishy. Those things are not held to the same standards; they often panic instead of handling errors gracefully, for instance. Also, http.NewRequest creates *outbound* requests, not server requests. There are subtile differences that may come back to bite you at some point.

Comment: *"can I know the reason"* -- The reason is that it doesn't work out-of-the-box as you've already learned. Handlers (and their middleware) are intended to handle their own requests, they aren't supposed to divide their labor between themselves. That's the design. You are going against the design. Even if what you're trying to do is possible it's still wrong. Whenever you have to resort to shenanigans it's a bad idea. Use the right tool for the job.

Comment: thanks for the response @mkopriva . I will follow your advice to convert Accept handler logic into a normal function and call it from both Accept and AcceptOrders